# Your computer appears to be correctly configured, but the device or resource (DNS server) is not responding" error message in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, router, dns

Windows 7Pro x64 8 GB RAM 
I have:
UNplugged my cable router and wireless router, plugged back in
flushed DNS, Register DNS, release IP, renew IP
Tried assigning a static address using googles DNS 8.8.8.8.  8.8.4.4

I CAN NOT get to the internet using Internet Explorer, Chrome or FireFox
BUT I CAN get to the internet using Safari for Windows.

I have no issues with my IMAC.

Other programs that access internet are successful.

Comment: An unwanted program may have changed your system proxy settings. Open the control panel and search for Internet Options. Open that, then switch to the Connections tab and click LAN Settings. You should see a checkbox next to some text that starts off with Use a proxy server.... If it's checked, uncheck it and see if that removes the ads. Let us know if that solves the problem or not.

Comment: The Proxy Server is not checked. Automatic Configuration , Automatically Detect Settings is checked. Can not access Internet with Internet Explorer, Firefox or Chrome.
I can access the internet with Safari for Windows.

Comment: Try setting the proxy configuration to "no proxy", instead of "automatic configuration".

Answer (score -1):

I used Windows Utility for the Last Known Good Configuration. When PC booted up I was then able to use all browsers to access the Internet.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer for others?  Which "Windows Utility" is that exactly?